# Creating an auto incremented id when user submits a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Currently I have a refno. column in my database with the format `LP00001`. Now I have a add page that inserts all data that the user inserts in the input field and all this data gets sent to a table in my database, but my refno column stays null which I want to have an auto incrementing value where the last 5 digits will be +1 everytime the user submits the form.

I do not want to have it be shown before the submit button as 2 users can be on that page at the same time which means they both will get the same id which means it has to generate it only at the time of submit. Currently this is my code:

Controller class:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $main['page'] = 'crm/listings/add';
            $this->load->view('crm/index', $main);
        }else {  
            $maindata=array('clients_id'=>$this->session->userdata('clientsessid'),
            'property_for'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('property_for')),
            'property_type'=>$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('property_type')));
            $insertid=$this->listings_model->insert_listing($maindata);
            if($insertid){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div>Successfully</div>');
                redirect('listings/sales');
```

Model Class:

```
function insert_listing($maindata){
    $this->db->insert("crm_listings",$maindata);
    $prime=$this->db->insert_id();
    return $prime;
}
```

So I assume I'll need to do this in my model class function `insert_listing` since that is called when I press submit button. Here another thing will be that the model will have to check what was the last entry in the database that has to be incremented for which I'm assuming I'll have to use `echo str_replace("LP","","LP00001");`

Comment: Just wonder - Did you consider using an auto_incremented key field in your db table ? (this will be assigned by the system automatically on record insertion)

Comment: @KenLee I did, but there are already 10000 records in the database with this format, so I want to continue to use auto increment from where it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just have to prepend the initials `LP` to the returned autoIncremented `id`.

```php
function insert_listing($maindata){
    // ...

    $this->db->set("refno", "LP". sprintf('%05d', $prime));
    $this->db->where('id', $prime);
    $this->db->update("crm_listings");

    return $prime;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't insert anything in my refno column in my database. I currently don't have 'refno' mentioned in my $maindata array since I only want it to be filled at the time of submit

Comment: @H2O , check my updated answer.

Comment: This gave Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::table() error

Comment: @H2O , sorry, I thought you're using Codeigniter 4, Since you're using Codeigniter 3, try my updated answer.